# When I Sometimes click on shopping button , it does not work javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a code that adds items to the cart (.products-container class) . The codes works awesome however sometimes when I click on the button , It does not work ! . This happens very randomly and I looked at the browser console for errors but none is given ! ( I think it has something to do with Script Loading )

```js
let cartNumStr = document.querySelector('.counter-eclipse-num').innerText;
let cartNum = Number(cartNumStr);
let sumPrice = document.querySelector('.sum-price').innerText;
sumPrice = Number(sumPrice);

document.querySelector(".polygon-cart").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("fa-trash")) {
      const container = tgt.closest(".cart-content-container");
      let qty = container.querySelector(".cart-qty").value;
      if (qty < 2){
        container.remove();
        cartNum = cartNum - 1;
        document.querySelector('.counter-eclipse-num').innerText = cartNum;
      }    
      else {
        qty = qty -1;
        container.querySelector(".cart-qty").value = qty;
        cartNum = cartNum - 1;
        document.querySelector('.counter-eclipse-num').innerText = cartNum;
        if (cartNum <10) {
          document.querySelector('.counter-eclipse-num').style.right = "5.2px";
        }
      }
    }
  });

function addCartNum() {
    cartNum = cartNum + 1;
    document.querySelector('.counter-eclipse-num').innerText = cartNum;
    if (cartNum > 9){
      document.querySelector('.counter-eclipse-num').style.right = "2.2px";
    }
}

document.querySelector(".products-container").addEventListener("click", function(f){
  fgt = f.target;
  if (fgt.classList.contains("fa-shopping-cart")){
    const container = fgt.closest(".product-1")
    let title = container.querySelector(".product-title").innerText;
    let price = container.querySelector(".product-price").innerText;
    let img = container.querySelector(".product-img").src;
    let cartContentContainer = document.createElement("div")
    cartContentContainer.classList.add('cart-content-container');
    let motherElement = document.querySelector(".main-cart-content-container");
    let cartItemContent =
    ` <p class="cart-price" dir="rtl">${price}</p>
      <div class="cart-qty-container">
          <input dir="rtl" type="number" min="1" value="1" class='cart-qty' id="cart-qty"oninput="this.value = 
          !!this.value && Math.abs(this.value) >= 0 ? Math.abs(this.value) : null">
          <label class="cart-qty-label" dir="rtl">تعداد &nbsp : &nbsp</label>
      </div>
      <a href="#" dir="rtl" class="cart-title">${title}</a>
      <i class="fas fa-trash" id = "trash-icon"></i>
      <div class="cart-product-img-container">
          <img src="${img}" class="cart-product-img">
      </div>
    `
    cartContentContainer.innerHTML = cartItemContent;
    motherElement.append(cartContentContainer);
    let realPrice = container.querySelector('.real-price').innerText;
    realPrice = Number(realPrice);
    sumPrice = sumPrice + realPrice;
    document.querySelector('.sum-price').innerText = sumPrice;
    addCartNum();
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Header.CSS">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.CSS">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Footer.CSS">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/38b3678073.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/JS/main.js" async></script>
    <title>خانه | PCGA</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="polygon-cart" id = "cart">
        <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id="cart-icon"></i>
        <div class="counter-eclipse">
            <p class="counter-eclipse-num">0</p>
        </div>
        <div class="main-cart-content-container" id = "main-cart-content-container">
            
        </div>
        <div class="cart-info-top">
            <button class="cart-checkout-btn">تسویه نهایی</button>
            <span class="cart-whole-price">جمع مبلغ سبد خرید شما : <span class = "sum-price">0</span> هزارتومان</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img src="img/Final-Logo.png" alt="Final-Logo" class="Final-Logo" height="171px" width="500px">
    <div class="SearchContainer">
        <table class="SearchTable">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="SearchBar">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#"><i class="SearchIcon"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <nav class="nav-top">
        <ul>
            <a href="/index.html"><li>خانه</li></a>
            <div class="nav-products">
                <a href="#"><li>محصولات</li></a>
                <ul class = products-dropdown-content>
                    <a href="/Products-Origin.html"><li>(Origin) اوریجین</li></a>
                    <a href="/Products-Steam.html"><li>(Steam) استیم</li></a>
                    <a href="/Products-Uplay.html"><li>(Uplay) یوپلی</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#"><li>تماس با ما</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>درباره ما</li></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>   
</header>
<div class = 'products-container'>
    <div class='product-1'>
        <div class="product-img-container">
            <img src="/img/BFV.jpg" class='product-img'>
            <div class = 'product-price'>قیمت : <span class="real-price">150000</span> تومان</div>
        </div>
        <section class='product-title'>
            <h1 dir="rtl"><a href="#">اکانت بازی  Battlefield V Deluxe Edition</a></h1>
        </section>
        <div class="product-des">
            <table class="info-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>ضمانت</th>
                    <th>قابلیت تغییر اطلاعات</th>
                    <th>پلتفرم</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5 ساله سبز</td>
                    <td>دارد</td>
                    <td>یوپلی</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button  class="buy-btn" ><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id= "addcartbtn"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='product-1'>
        <div class="product-img-container">
            <img src="/img/BFV.jpg" class='product-img'>
            <div class = 'product-price'>قیمت : <span class="real-price">520000</span> تومان</div>
        </div>
        <section class='product-title'>
            <h1 dir="rtl"><a href="#">اکانت بازی  Battlefield V Deluxe Edition</a></h1>
        </section>
        <div class="product-des">
            <table class="info-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>ضمانت</th>
                    <th>قابلیت تغییر اطلاعات</th>
                    <th>پلتفرم</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5 ساله سبز</td>
                    <td>دارد</td>
                    <td>یوپلی</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button  class="buy-btn" ><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id= "addcartbtn"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='product-1'>
        <div class="product-img-container">
            <img src="/img/BFV.jpg" class='product-img'>
            <div class = 'product-price'>قیمت : <span class="real-price">750000</span> تومان</div>
        </div>
        <section class='product-title'>
            <h1 dir="rtl"><a href="#">اکانت بازی  Battlefield V Deluxe Edition</a></h1>
        </section>
        <div class="product-des">
            <table class="info-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>ضمانت</th>
                    <th>قابلیت تغییر اطلاعات</th>
                    <th>پلتفرم</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5 ساله سبز</td>
                    <td>دارد</td>
                    <td>یوپلی</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button class="buy-btn" ><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id= "addcartbtn"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='product-1'>
        <div class="product-img-container">
            <img src="/img/BFV.jpg" class='product-img'>
            <div class = 'product-price'>قیمت : <span class="real-price">50000</span> تومان</div>
        </div>
        <section class='product-title'>
            <h1 dir="rtl"><a href="#">اکانت بازی  Battlefield V Deluxe Edition</a></h1>
        </section>
        <div class="product-des">
            <table class="info-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>ضمانت</th>
                    <th>قابلیت تغییر اطلاعات</th>
                    <th>پلتفرم</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5 ساله سبز</td>
                    <td>دارد</td>
                    <td>یوپلی</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button class="buy-btn" ><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id= "addcartbtn"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='product-1'>
        <div class="product-img-container">
            <img src="/img/BFV.jpg" class='product-img'>
            <div class = 'product-price'>قیمت : <span class="real-price">24000</span> تومان</div>
        </div>
        <section class='product-title'>
            <h1 dir="rtl"><a href="#">اکانت بازی  Battlefield V Deluxe Edition</a></h1>
        </section>
        <div class="product-des">
            <table class="info-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>ضمانت</th>
                    <th>قابلیت تغییر اطلاعات</th>
                    <th>پلتفرم</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5 ساله سبز</td>
                    <td>دارد</td>
                    <td>یوپلی</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button class="buy-btn" ><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id= "addcartbtn"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='product-1'>
        <div class="product-img-container">
            <img src="/img/BFV.jpg" class='product-img'>
            <div class = 'product-price'>قیمت : <span class="real-price">36000</span> تومان</div>
        </div>
        <section class='product-title'>
            <h1 dir="rtl"><a href="#">اکانت بازی  Battlefield V Deluxe Edition</a></h1>
        </section>
        <div class="product-des">
            <table class="info-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>ضمانت</th>
                    <th>قابلیت تغییر اطلاعات</th>
                    <th>پلتفرم</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5 ساله سبز</td>
                    <td>دارد</td>
                    <td>یوپلی</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button class="buy-btn" ><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id= "addcartbtn"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="pagination">
    <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#" class="active">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
    <a href="#">4</a>
    <a href="#">5</a>
    <a href="#">6</a>
    <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
</div>

<footer class = 'footer-main'>
    <div class='footer-content'>
        <div class='col-1'>
            <h3>محصولات</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/Products-Origin.html">(Origin) اوریجین</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products-Steam.html">(Steam) استیم</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products-Uplay.html">(Uplay) یوپلی</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='col-2'>
            <h3>حساب&nbsp کاربری</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/page/login.html">ورود</a></li>
                <li><a href="/page/register.html">ثبت نام</a></li>
                <li><a href="/page/orders.html">سفارشات من</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='col-3'>
            <h3>پشتیبانی</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">سوالات متداول</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">قوانین</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">تماس با ما</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">درباره ما</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='col-4'>
            <img src="/img/bonyad-mojavez.png" class="mojavez-pic">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='footer-copyright' dir="rtl">Copyright PCGA.info 2021, all rights reserved | تمامی حقوق برای فروشگاه پی سی جی ای محفوظ است <br> طراحی و توسعه توسط نیما صیادی</div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do we have to do to reproduce this? I tried clicking on the cart icon a number of times, and it always added an item to the cart.

Comment: Hm, Seems the button isn't clicked well so the item isn't added like you expected.

Comment: Most of the times when I refresh my page , at first It does not work for a few times . Sometime it works ! This is very odd ! Try removing and adding several times very quickly and you will face my problem . It's like a delay of some sort . I use Live Server extension on VS Code

Comment: Yeah, it seems actually firing nothing with clicking the button quickly! That's odd!

Comment: I tried to find errors at Script Loading but I didn't found any problem with the issue. But I added an answer for your question. So check it out!

Comment: Could be a race condition with the addEventListener calls.
If that code executes before the elements have been created in the DOM.
It would probably be safer to put the "onclick" handler element in the HTML directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the event is only contained in `fa-shopping-cart` class, when you click the outside line of the `icon` tag which is `button` tag, the event isn't executed.

So I added event from below,

```
if (fgt.classList.contains("fa-shopping-cart")){
...
}
```

to this below,

```
if (fgt.classList.contains("buy-btn")||fgt.classList.contains("fa-shopping-cart")){
...
}
```

So the button event is executed whenever you click on the buttons.

```js
let cartNumStr = document.querySelector('.counter-eclipse-num').innerText;
let cartNum = Number(cartNumStr);
let sumPrice = document.querySelector('.sum-price').innerText;
sumPrice = Number(sumPrice);

document.querySelector(".polygon-cart").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("fa-trash")) {
      const container = tgt.closest(".cart-content-container");
      let qty = container.querySelector(".cart-qty").value;
      if (qty < 2){
        container.remove();
        cartNum = cartNum - 1;
        document.querySelector('.counter-eclipse-num').innerText = cartNum;
      }    
      else {
        qty = qty -1;
        container.querySelector(".cart-qty").value = qty;
        cartNum = cartNum - 1;
        document.querySelector('.counter-eclipse-num').innerText = cartNum;
        if (cartNum <10) {
          document.querySelector('.counter-eclipse-num').style.right = "5.2px";
        }
      }
    }
  });

function addCartNum() {
    cartNum = cartNum + 1;
    document.querySelector('.counter-eclipse-num').innerText = cartNum;
    if (cartNum > 9){
      document.querySelector('.counter-eclipse-num').style.right = "2.2px";
    }
}

document.querySelector(".products-container").addEventListener("click", function(f){
  fgt = f.target;
  ///// I edited this condition
  //// from if (fgt.classList.contains("fa-shopping-cart")){
  //// to this below
  if (fgt.classList.contains("buy-btn")||fgt.classList.contains("fa-shopping-cart")){
  ///// I edited this condition
    const container = fgt.closest(".product-1")
    let title = container.querySelector(".product-title").innerText;
    let price = container.querySelector(".product-price").innerText;
    let img = container.querySelector(".product-img").src;
    let cartContentContainer = document.createElement("div")
    cartContentContainer.classList.add('cart-content-container');
    let motherElement = document.querySelector(".main-cart-content-container");
    let cartItemContent =
    ` <p class="cart-price" dir="rtl">${price}</p>
      <div class="cart-qty-container">
          <input dir="rtl" type="number" min="1" value="1" class='cart-qty' id="cart-qty"oninput="this.value = 
          !!this.value && Math.abs(this.value) >= 0 ? Math.abs(this.value) : null">
          <label class="cart-qty-label" dir="rtl">تعداد &nbsp : &nbsp</label>
      </div>
      <a href="#" dir="rtl" class="cart-title">${title}</a>
      <i class="fas fa-trash" id = "trash-icon"></i>
      <div class="cart-product-img-container">
          <img src="${img}" class="cart-product-img">
      </div>
    `
    cartContentContainer.innerHTML = cartItemContent;
    motherElement.append(cartContentContainer);
    let realPrice = container.querySelector('.real-price').innerText;
    realPrice = Number(realPrice);
    sumPrice = sumPrice + realPrice;
    document.querySelector('.sum-price').innerText = sumPrice;
    addCartNum();
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Header.CSS">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.CSS">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Footer.CSS">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/38b3678073.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/JS/main.js" async></script>
    <title>خانه | PCGA</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="polygon-cart" id = "cart">
        <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id="cart-icon"></i>
        <div class="counter-eclipse">
            <p class="counter-eclipse-num">0</p>
        </div>
        <div class="main-cart-content-container" id = "main-cart-content-container">
        </div>
        <div class="cart-info-top">
            <button class="cart-checkout-btn">تسویه نهایی</button>
            <span class="cart-whole-price">جمع مبلغ سبد خرید شما : <span class = "sum-price">0</span> هزارتومان</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img src="img/Final-Logo.png" alt="Final-Logo" class="Final-Logo" height="171px" width="500px">
    <div class="SearchContainer">
        <table class="SearchTable">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="SearchBar">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#"><i class="SearchIcon"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <nav class="nav-top">
        <ul>
            <a href="/index.html"><li>خانه</li></a>
            <div class="nav-products">
                <a href="#"><li>محصولات</li></a>
                <ul class = products-dropdown-content>
                    <a href="/Products-Origin.html"><li>(Origin) اوریجین</li></a>
                    <a href="/Products-Steam.html"><li>(Steam) استیم</li></a>
                    <a href="/Products-Uplay.html"><li>(Uplay) یوپلی</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <a href="#"><li>تماس با ما</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li>درباره ما</li></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>   
</header>
<div class = 'products-container'>
    <div class='product-1'>
        <div class="product-img-container">
            <img src="/img/BFV.jpg" class='product-img'>
            <div class = 'product-price'>قیمت : <span class="real-price">150000</span> تومان</div>
        </div>
        <section class='product-title'>
            <h1 dir="rtl"><a href="#">اکانت بازی  Battlefield V Deluxe Edition</a></h1>
        </section>
        <div class="product-des">
            <table class="info-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>ضمانت</th>
                    <th>قابلیت تغییر اطلاعات</th>
                    <th>پلتفرم</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5 ساله سبز</td>
                    <td>دارد</td>
                    <td>یوپلی</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button  class="buy-btn" ><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id= "addcartbtn"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='product-1'>
        <div class="product-img-container">
            <img src="/img/BFV.jpg" class='product-img'>
            <div class = 'product-price'>قیمت : <span class="real-price">520000</span> تومان</div>
        </div>
        <section class='product-title'>
            <h1 dir="rtl"><a href="#">اکانت بازی  Battlefield V Deluxe Edition</a></h1>
        </section>
        <div class="product-des">
            <table class="info-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>ضمانت</th>
                    <th>قابلیت تغییر اطلاعات</th>
                    <th>پلتفرم</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5 ساله سبز</td>
                    <td>دارد</td>
                    <td>یوپلی</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button  class="buy-btn" ><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id= "addcartbtn"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='product-1'>
        <div class="product-img-container">
            <img src="/img/BFV.jpg" class='product-img'>
            <div class = 'product-price'>قیمت : <span class="real-price">750000</span> تومان</div>
        </div>
        <section class='product-title'>
            <h1 dir="rtl"><a href="#">اکانت بازی  Battlefield V Deluxe Edition</a></h1>
        </section>
        <div class="product-des">
            <table class="info-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>ضمانت</th>
                    <th>قابلیت تغییر اطلاعات</th>
                    <th>پلتفرم</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5 ساله سبز</td>
                    <td>دارد</td>
                    <td>یوپلی</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button class="buy-btn" ><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id= "addcartbtn"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='product-1'>
        <div class="product-img-container">
            <img src="/img/BFV.jpg" class='product-img'>
            <div class = 'product-price'>قیمت : <span class="real-price">50000</span> تومان</div>
        </div>
        <section class='product-title'>
            <h1 dir="rtl"><a href="#">اکانت بازی  Battlefield V Deluxe Edition</a></h1>
        </section>
        <div class="product-des">
            <table class="info-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>ضمانت</th>
                    <th>قابلیت تغییر اطلاعات</th>
                    <th>پلتفرم</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5 ساله سبز</td>
                    <td>دارد</td>
                    <td>یوپلی</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button class="buy-btn" ><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id= "addcartbtn"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='product-1'>
        <div class="product-img-container">
            <img src="/img/BFV.jpg" class='product-img'>
            <div class = 'product-price'>قیمت : <span class="real-price">24000</span> تومان</div>
        </div>
        <section class='product-title'>
            <h1 dir="rtl"><a href="#">اکانت بازی  Battlefield V Deluxe Edition</a></h1>
        </section>
        <div class="product-des">
            <table class="info-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>ضمانت</th>
                    <th>قابلیت تغییر اطلاعات</th>
                    <th>پلتفرم</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5 ساله سبز</td>
                    <td>دارد</td>
                    <td>یوپلی</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button class="buy-btn" ><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id= "addcartbtn"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='product-1'>
        <div class="product-img-container">
            <img src="/img/BFV.jpg" class='product-img'>
            <div class = 'product-price'>قیمت : <span class="real-price">36000</span> تومان</div>
        </div>
        <section class='product-title'>
            <h1 dir="rtl"><a href="#">اکانت بازی  Battlefield V Deluxe Edition</a></h1>
        </section>
        <div class="product-des">
            <table class="info-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>ضمانت</th>
                    <th>قابلیت تغییر اطلاعات</th>
                    <th>پلتفرم</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5 ساله سبز</td>
                    <td>دارد</td>
                    <td>یوپلی</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <button class="buy-btn" ><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart" id= "addcartbtn"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="pagination">
    <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#" class="active">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
    <a href="#">4</a>
    <a href="#">5</a>
    <a href="#">6</a>
    <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
</div>

<footer class = 'footer-main'>
    <div class='footer-content'>
        <div class='col-1'>
            <h3>محصولات</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/Products-Origin.html">(Origin) اوریجین</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products-Steam.html">(Steam) استیم</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Products-Uplay.html">(Uplay) یوپلی</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='col-2'>
            <h3>حساب&nbsp کاربری</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/page/login.html">ورود</a></li>
                <li><a href="/page/register.html">ثبت نام</a></li>
                <li><a href="/page/orders.html">سفارشات من</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='col-3'>
            <h3>پشتیبانی</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">سوالات متداول</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">قوانین</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">تماس با ما</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">درباره ما</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='col-4'>
            <img src="/img/bonyad-mojavez.png" class="mojavez-pic">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='footer-copyright' dir="rtl">Copyright PCGA.info 2021, all rights reserved | تمامی حقوق برای فروشگاه پی سی جی ای محفوظ است <br> طراحی و توسعه توسط نیما صیادی</div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```